# While deploying two application authenticated using Azure AD on a single IIS server, Authentication page keeps on looping infinitely

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, iis, azure-active-directory

I have created two .NET applications having Azure AD authentication. I have deployed both of them on the IIS server with different ports for HTTP and HTTPS.

1st Application: Deployed on HTTP Port 80 and HTTPS Port 443 with the Redirect URL of app1.xyz.com

2nd Application: Deployed on HTTP Port 88 and HTTPS Port 9443 with the Redirect URL of https://app2.xyz.com:9443

While authenticating a user for 1st Application, Authentication flow is working fine where the user is redirected to Login Page and after successful login, the user is redirected back to the application URL.

Where authenticating a user for 2nd Application, Authentication flow is not working fine where the user is redirected to Login page and it keeps on looping infinitely on the login page.

Could anyone please share your comments/suggestions on the above issue?

Comment: Still if you have any question just let me know here in comment. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As it is common issue may be you have not chosen a pattern syntax and so you using the default regular expression syntax on your web config file, On the fly which I am assuming the causes for an infinite loop. Though you have not share your web config file but you can try this:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <configuration>
    <system.webServer>
      <rewrite>
        <rules>
          <rule name="Add www" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="*" />
            <conditions>
              <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="example.com" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.example.com/{R:0}" />
          </rule>
        </rules>
      </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
  </configuration>
```

Note: Replace your desired URL On Code.

For more information you can click here...https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaushal/2013/05/22/http-to-https-redirects-on-iis-7-x-and-higher/